# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable?

Tags: python, numpy

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

This code is for basic autonomous navigation of a small all terrain vehicle.  For some reason it's getting caught in the heading and bearing calculation functions.  I've tried putting either one first in the run function, and it does the same thing.

I'm fairly inexperienced with python, so it's likely something simple that I am overlooking.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3Stamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
from math import radians
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
import time
import numpy

lat = 0.0
lon = 0.0
x = 0.0
y = 0.0
z = 0.0
head = 0.0
bear = 0.0


###########################################################
destLat = 30.210406
#                                   Destination
destLon = -92.022914
############################################################


class sub():

    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('Test1', anonymous=False)
        rospy.Subscriber("/imu_um6/mag", Vector3Stamped, self.call_1)
        rospy.Subscriber("/gps/fix", NavSatFix, self.call_2)

    def call_1(self, mag):
        global x
        global y
        global z
        x = mag.vector.x
        y= mag.vector.y
        z= mag.vector.z
    
    def call_2(self, gps):
        global lat
        global lon

        lat = gps.latitude
        lon = gps.longitude

def head(lat, lon):
    global head
    # Define heading here
    head = numpy.rad2deg(numpy.arctan2(z, y)) + 90
    print(head)


def bear(y,z):
    global bear
    # Define bearing Here
    dLon = destLon - lon
    vert = numpy.sin(dLon) * numpy.cos(destLat)
    horiz = numpy.cos(lat)*numpy.sin(destLat) - numpy.sin(lat)*numpy.cos(destLat)*numpy.cos(dLon)
    bear = (numpy.rad2deg(numpy.arctan2(vert, horiz)) + 360) % 360
    print(bear)


def nav(head, bear, destLat, destLon):
    # Do Navigation Here
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    move_cmd = Twist()
    turn_cmd = Twist()

    move_cmd.linear.x = 2
    turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(45)

    turn_angle = head - bear
#   Prettify the angle 
    if (turn_angle > 180):
        turn_angle -= 360
    elif (turn_angle < -180):
        turn_angle += 360
    else:
        turn_angle = turn_angle

    if (abs(lat-destLat)<.0005 and abs(lon-destLon)<.0005):
        pub.publish(Twist())
        r.sleep()
    else:
        if (abs(turn_angle) < 8):
            pub.publish(move_cmd)
            rospy.spin()
        else:
            pub.publish(turn_cmd)
            r = rospy.Rate(5);
            r.sleep()
    


def shutdown(self):
    rospy.loginfo("Stop Husky")
    cmd_vel.publish(Twist())
    rospy.sleep(1)


def run():
    sub()
    bear(y,z)
    head(lat,lon)
    nav(head, bear, destLat, destLon)
    print('here')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            run()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.loginfo("stopped")
        pass
```

Here's the whole output:

```
163.11651134
90.0
here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classTest.py", line 117, in <module>
    run()
  File "classTest.py", line 107, in run
    bear(y,z)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Comment: Notice that `run` works one time; it's the second call that encounters a different `bear` (and `head`).  I would try to get rid of this `globals` approach to saving the state.  Saving state as attributes of a class object is better.  But I'm not sure how that will play with the `rosby` calls.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't use the same variable name for a function and a float (in the same namespace). And you both defined a `bear` function and a `bear` variable pointing to a float. You need to change one of the two names.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong, so wrong!!!  :)

```
def bear(y,z):
    global bear
    ....
```

Comment: While I completely agree with this, I don't know if this answer clearly answers the OP's question.

Comment: Of itself it probably isn't the cause.  You could get this error without the `global`.  But the juxtaposition of these lines points to some funny business in using the identifier `bear`.  Maybe the programmer is used to language that keeps variables and functions in different namespaces.  Also overuse of `global` is a common rookie mistake,